# Trouble converting simple PNG download script from PHP to Java

Tags: java, php, servlets, base64

I'm trying to download a PNG image from a Flash application using a Java servlet.  I was using this PHP script, which worked perfectly, but need to switch to a Java servlet instead.

PHP:

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: image/png');
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=out.png");
   echo base64_decode($_POST["image"]);
?>
```

And my Java code:

```
String image = getRequest().getParameter("image");
String decodedImage = new String(Base64.decode(image));
HttpServletResponse resp = op.getResponse();
resp.setContentType("image/png");
resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=out.png");
resp.getWriter().write(image);
resp.getWriter().flush();
```

I've tried two separate Base64 decoder classes with the same results.  The decoded base64 is written as a response but the PNG is corrupt.  One difference I can see in the HTTP response header is that the Servlet uses "image/png; charset=UTF-8" while the PHP script just uses "image/png".

Thanks for the help!

FIX - thanks Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams!

```
resp.setContentType("image/png");
resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=out.png");
resp.getOutputStream().write(image);
resp.getOutputStream().close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.getOutputStream()`, not `.getWriter()`. You need to send it as binary data.